# How do I filter by date and count these dates using relational algebra (Reframe)?

Tags: pandas, relational-database, pandas-groupby, relational-algebra

I'm really stuck. I read the Reframe documentation https://reframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ that's based on pandas and I tried multiple things on my own but it still doesn't work. So I got a CSV file called weddings that looks like this:

```
Weddings, Date
Wedding1,20181107
Wedding2,20181107
```

And many more rows. As you can see, there are duplicates in the date column but this doesn't matter I think. I want to count the amount of weddings filtered by date, for example, the amount of weddings after 5 october 2016 (20161005). So first I tried this:

```
Weddings = Relation('weddings.csv')
Weddings.sort(['Date']).query('Date > 20161005').project(['Weddings', 'Date'])
```

This seems logical to me but I get a Keyerror 'Date' and don't know why? So I tried something more simple

```
Weddings = Relation('weddings.csv')
Weddings.groupby(['Date']).count()
```

And this doesn't work either, I still get a Keyerror 'Date' and don't know why. Can someone help me?

Track trace

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-b358cdf55fdb> in <module>()
  1 
  2 Weddings = Relation('weddings.csv')
----> 3 weddings.sort(['Date']).query('Date > 20161005').project(['Weddings', 'Date'])
  4 
  5 

~\Documents\Reframe.py in sort(self, *args, 
**kwargs)
110         """
111 
--> 112         return Relation(super().sort_values(*args, **kwargs))
113 
114     def intersect(self, other):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in sort_values(self, by, 
axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position)
4416             by = by[0]
4417             k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by, axis=axis,
-> 4418                                                 stacklevel=stacklevel)
4419 
4420             if isinstance(ascending, (tuple, list)):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in 
_get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis, stacklevel)
1377             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
1378         else:
-> 1379             raise KeyError(key)
1380 
1381         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'Date'
```

Comment: can you print `df.columns` you may have white space on your columns

Comment: @Datanovice  I got this, is this how it's supposed to be? Index(['Weddings', 'Date'], dtype='object')

Comment: doesn't look like any whitespace, you should post the full stack trace

Comment: 1377             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1378         else:
-> 1379             raise KeyError(key)
   1380 
   1381         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'Date'

Comment: @Datanovice I'll add the whole trace to my post

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please give a [mre]. Does relation(df) work? Please print the original value of Weddings. Does just rename work? Does just query? "reframe.Relation(filepath=None, sep='|')" "sep – specify a separator for the data file. default is |" So did you give all your code? According to the specification the csv should be taken as having 1 column. PS Sorting before other operators is not likely useful except to give a df since other operators aren't documented to do anything in particular with order. (But the documentation is poor.)